# ASP.NET MVC area namespace problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

I create a new area in my asp.net mvc 3 solution named **admin**. Visual studio automatically assign the names space:

```
MyApp.areas.admin.controllers
```

I change this to `MyApp.admin.controllers`

But it stops resolving the action.
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why does the namespace matter?

Comment: Have you changed anything else?  Moved files, renamed folders, removed the route registration from the area registration file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to specify the new namespace when registering the route for your admin area.

In your \Areas\admin\adminAreaRegistration.cs file, you need to modify the RegisterArea() method as follows:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "admin_default",
        "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
        new string[] { "MyApp.admin.Controllers" }  // specify the new namespace
    );
}
```