# .NET MVC3 Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Customer'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Customer'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Customer' has found the following matching controllers:
OpenCart.Cotrollers.CustomerController
OpenCart.Areas.Admin.Controllers.CustomerController
```

my routes is follow:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // 路由名称
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // 带有参数的 URL
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // 参数默认值
    namespaces: new string[] { "OpenCart.Controllers" }//设置域，与Admin区分
);
```

and areas routes:

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",//Admin路由
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },//默认参数
        namespaces: new string[] { "OpenCart.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }//**设置该路由所对应的Controller
    );
```

but when I request /Customer/Register it do not work~Why?

Comment: have a look at his post, it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752644/asp-net-mvc-area-namespace-problem

Comment: I have a areas route:context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",//Admin路由
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },//默认参数
        namespaces: new string[] { "OpenCart.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }//**设置该路由所对应的Controller
    );  and have set namespaces.but it don't work.

Comment: try removing the namespaces: and have it as just new string[] { "OpenCart.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }//**设置该路由所对应的Controller

Comment: I found the problem.The reason is that the namespace：OpenCart.Controllers I wrote ：OpenCart.Cotrollers in the Controller.it's my careless to make this mistake.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad you solved it :)